# How to refer to named forms with "controller as" syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble referring to named forms in my controller when using the "controller as" syntax in angularjs. For example, given the following HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as ctl">
  <form role="form" name="newItemForm">
    <input type="text" id="firstName" ng-model="ctl.firstName"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

In the context of the controller,

```
function MyController() {
  var self = this;
  console.log(self.newItemForm);
}
```

`self.newItemForm` is undefined. If I had been using the $scope convention, I could have referred to $scope.newItemForm. Is there any other way of doing this in the controller as syntax without using the scope?

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('newItemForm')` comes to mind ?

Comment: adeneo, that would get you the DOM element, but not the angular FormController, which is used to set the validity of form elements in angularjs.

Comment: See the docs on how to implement custom validation http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms you shouldn't be accessing DOM elements directly from a controller it should just have the model and functions to modify the model used for the view.

Comment: shaunhusain, perhaps I didn't explain well, but I'm _not_ accessing DOM elements. I'm trying to use the $scope.newItemForm.input.$setValidity() syntax, but when you're using the "controller as" syntax, you don't usually access the scope directly, so you need another way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification was more responding to adeneo on that part since they mentioned using document within the controller.  In the examples I don't see anywhere they access the form is there a reason using a directive as shown in the docs doesn't work out for you?  I'm not super familiar with validation details myself.

Comment: Using directives works fine, when it makes sense to do so. But there are cases where you need to set validity in the controller, such as when you make an ajax call and discover that there is a duplicate field in the database. In these cases, you want to set a specific field as invalid inside a controller method, but when you're using the "controller as" syntax, I see no clear way of referring to a named form.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Change your HTML to this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as ctl">
  <form role="form" name="ctl.newItemForm">
    <input type="text" id="firstName" ng-model="ctl.firstName"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Then you will be able to access the named form as expected in your controller without injecting `$scope`. Found this information here: http://www.technofattie.com/2014/07/01/using-angular-forms-with-controller-as-syntax.html

Comment: Is this a good practice? by doing this i understand you're attaching the whole form to the controller! Instead you could inject $scope and the form would bind automatically to it.

Comment: @DSB that's true, but using separate, named controller brings you a much cleaner separation, see:
https://toddmotto.com/a-better-way-to-scope-angular-extend-no-more-vm-this/ and https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: Not getting access to input's validation, though. For that, I've found one has to use "name" attribute in the input and access it through ```ctl.form.firstName.$dirty``` and etc (not just ```ctl.firstName``` which points to variable in the controller)